# My text has margin on the top and bottom. Why?

Tags: html, css

```css
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </h1>
  <h3>
    Duis dictum eget lacus nec molestie Integer non nisl leo
  </h3>
  <h5>
    Quisque eu luctus tellus. Mauris et dictum ante
  </h5>
</div>
```

when I run this in my browser,

- my `h1`element has 16.080 px of margin on the top and bottom
- my `h3`element has 14.040 px of margin on the top and bottom
- my `h5`element has 16.633 px of margin on the top and bottom

The result I want is this:

```css
.title {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </h1>
  <h3 class="title">
    Duis dictum eget lacus nec molestie Integer non nisl leo
  </h3>
  <h5 class="title">
    Quisque eu luctus tellus. Mauris et dictum ante
  </h5>
</div>
```

This gives me the result I want, but I do not want to have the `class="title"` for all my `h`elements.

How do I do this WITHOUT USING three `class="title"`s?

Comment: `* { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @dustytrash your comment was helpful. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headings tags (h1, h2, h3 etc) come with default styles. See here - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

One of the default styles is margin. You can easily remove this with css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .header {
      text-align: center
    }
    h1, h3, h5 {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </h1>
    <h3>
      Duis dictum eget lacus nec molestie Integer non nisl leo
    </h3>
    <h5>
      Quisque eu luctus tellus. Mauris et dictum ante
    </h5>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CSS use:

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```